# How to capture MLflow Experiment description programmatically?

Tags: mlflow, mlops

I am trying to capture the MLflow experiment descriptions programmatically. I don't find any option as such in create or set experiments parameters. Is there a way to address this?

I tried to use the create/set_experiment when creating experiment in MLflow, but they don't have option to capture the experiment descriptions programmatically. Is there any different option available apart from having the description via UI?

Comment: I see descriptions being used in TerraForm so this should be possible, will try to find a direct way
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/mlflow_experiment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tag your experiment appropriately**, in this case use `mlflow.note.content` tag.

```
experiment_id = mlflow.create_experiment(
   'my-experiment',
   tags={'mlflow.note.content':'this experiment is doing nothing'}
)
```

PS: How to figure it out, as this seems not well documented? Assign a description with GUI, and then inspect it in the backend :-)

[image: MLFlow experiment with description]

Comment: I was more or less sure, we could make this dynamic but was difficult to get in available documentations. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @IndrajitRoy you are welcome, I have had similar experience with undocumented features of other ml trackers:-) if this solves your problem let's accept it for others searching for it :-)

Comment: Indeed..this worked...accepted :)